# how to match a specific type of string in bash using regex

Tags: regex, bash

I want to write a script that matches everything that has either a character from the alphabet, a number, and an underscore.
Possible valid strings:

```
asd_asd
Asd_asd
asd_123
123_asd
123_aSD
```

and so on.
What I tried so far is:

```
if [[ "$LINE" =~ [a-zA-Z0-9_] ]]
```

But this will match any character that contains also any of these: !@#$%^&*()_+}{|?><`!, and other weird symbols.

I thought about putting the special characters in a list, and ignore a string if it contains one of the characters in the list, but I am afraid I can skip one character.

What is it better to do in this case?

Comment: Can you clarify what strings you want to match? It sounds like you want to match strings that consist *entirely* of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, is that correct? What about the empty (zero-length) string? BTW, your current pattern will match strings that contain *at least one* `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (that is, "@@@@a@@@@" would match, but "@@@@" wouldn't).

Comment: You probably need a ^ at the beginning and a $ at the end so that the whole like is the pattern And nothing else.  You may need to surround the whole thing in single quotes to prevent bash interpolation.

Comment: I noted that my question was not well formated. I edited it so the examples are clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` matches only one character. You need to use a pattern like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the input string,
- `$` matches the end of it,
- `[...]+` matches one or more characters from the character class (`a-zA-Z0-9_` in above pattern).